# Razor reference not working for .NETCoreApp 1.1 with Resharper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, resharper

I am trying to use the Razor framework within an ASP.NET Core project (.NETCoreApp 1.1), however, after retrieving the package from Nuget, the reference is not recognized by VS.

[image: Reference error]

I'm rather unfamiliar with the framework, is there something I am missing ? All Razor MVC generated pages work, although they are not recognized as so by Visual Studio. Hence the following happens:
[image: Intellisense error]

Can you please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the first answer from A.T., Resharper got an error triggered and it turned out that it was causing the issue.
To solve this issue, Pause and then Resume resharper (in Tools->Options->Resharper)
[image: Suspend and resume resharper]

Answer (score 1):

you might need to add these references in your project,

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools
```

Comment: Whilst adding these packages I had a resharper error. Suspending then resuming it solved the issue. I can only assume it was messing with intellisense.